# How to fetch "Customize Application permission" values for a user through an API call

Tags: api, metadata-api, permissions

I'm trying to find out how to (programmatically) determine if a user has the required permissions to for certain actions.

Specifically, according to this page https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.meta_modify_metadata_perm.htm&type=5 , Salesforce says that someone needs to "have the Customize Application permission to create, update, and delete metadata records".

So my question is, how can I obtain this information via an API call? I've been searching for some time now but have not been able to find any answers.

Comment: Is that user the running user?

Comment: @AdrianLarson The user I'd like to get this info for will have just oauthed into Salesforce

Answer (score 1):

A query like this can answer that question:

```
SELECT COUNT()
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND
  PermissionSet.PermissionsCustomizeApplication = true
```

If you get a value greater than zero, then the user has permission to customize the application either by Profile or Permission Set.

Comment: is there a way do do this with an http api call instead of a query?

Comment: @jerfp You can use a REST API call, it's still going to be a query, though.

Comment: would it ever be possible that a user doesn't have the permissions to make this query?